# Can i use WordPress plugin if i install WordPress with sql

Tags: sql, wordpress

i am working on project and i want to use WordPress for that but my client want Microsoft SQL for database, So my question is that if i use Microsoft SQL database, **all WordPress plugin is supported for that and can i use $wpdb function to handle database** and what i need to change in config file and what i do for setup WordPress with Microsoft SQL that?

Comment: See [Installing Wordpress on SQL Server](http://wordpress.visitmix.com/development/installing-wordpress-on-sql-server)

Comment: thanks for that but all plugin is supported to that or not?

Comment: No, since the majority of plugins create their own tables and you'd have to restructure such queries so they'd work for MSSQL.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see on [this](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/10918) post it's still not supported.